# I am having issues with JBoss/Wildfly. I am getting a timeout

Tags: jboss, timeout, wildfly

The below is my request and the corresponding response:

```
Sync App Status
org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the controller
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:278)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.main(CliLauncher.java:241)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineMain.main(CommandLineMain.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:292)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:455)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineException: The controller is not available at localhost:9990
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:1020)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:832)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:811)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:276)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:71)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:997)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:204)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(CLIModelControllerClient.java:169)
        at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient$2.getChannel(CLIModelControllerClient.java:129)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:117)
        at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:92)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:127)
        ... 13 more
```

I get the same response while trying to shutdown the server or anything else. Anyone know what can be causing this issue or a workaround?

Comment: did you bind the management interface to a different ip/host than localhost or a different port? Or is your firewall restricting access to that port, ...?

Comment: There were no changes on that VM, I was finally able to restart the app and it's working now! I will update if the error re-occurs. I believe it could have been a network/connectivity issue in our local env